# How to configure nginx to proxy MongoDB daemon in ssl mode?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, nginx

I have configured MongoDB according to https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/ to use SSL. And it works fine.

Now I need to place it behind the nginx.
When I use following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       27017;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:12345/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 110m;
    }

    add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
}
```

When I try to connect I have received:

{com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by 
{javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?}

So Ihave added nginx ssl directive:

```
server {
    listen       27017 ssl;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:12345/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 110m;
    }

    add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
}
```

After that I have received:

{com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket},  caused by 
{javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake}, caused by 
{java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does mongo works via HTTP? Maybe you need stream proxy?

Comment: And why you ever want it behind nginx?

Comment: Nginx to restrict access by ip.

Comment: when open in browser: It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

Comment: To restrict access there is firewall (iptables, ufw, etc.)

Comment: Yes you right. Nginx not needed. Thanx.